# Caliburn.Micro - How to display multiple items in WPF View from ViewModel that inherits: Conductor<object>.Collection.AllActive

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro as my MVVM framework in a WPF application. I am trying to include several custom user controls in one page which change dynamically based on user interaction. I understand that the CM convention is that the View will bind to the `Items` property within the ViewModel.

My question is:

1. How do I get access to each item within the `Items` collection property of the ViewModel in my View?
2. Can I individually place each item on the parent View page as I would normally be able to do with a normal WPF Control?

The basic appearance of the view page is shown here.
[View page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vlyX.jpg)

The basic ViewModel code:

```
  public class TestViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.AllActive
    {
        public TestViewModel()
        {
            Items.Add(new CustomUC1ViewModel());
            Items.Add(new CustomUC2ViewModel());
            Items.Add(new CustomUC3ViewModel());
        }
        //following logic would reassign the Items collection as required
    }
```

The ViewModels attached to `Items` would change dynamically based on user interaction with the parent page and the embedded user controls.

I hope the above makes sense (this is my first ever post).

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the answer to my problem. By assigning my user control views as `IScreen` properties in the ViewModel I was able to locate the user control whereever I want in the view through naming a `ContentControl` to match the relevant property in the ViewModel. The relevant property in the ViewModel can be changed and the view updates accordingly if using `NotifyOfPropertyChange()` in the setter.

In MyViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.AllActive 
{
    //the user control property where MainContent = new OtherViewModel()
    private IScreen _mainContent;
    public IScreen MainContent
    {
        get { return _mainContent; }
        set 
        {
            _mainContent = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MainContent);
        }
    }
}
```

In MyView in XAML:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MainContent"/>
```

The `Items` property in the ViewModel is instead just used to manage the lifecycle of the active windows. I was able to use multiple `<ContentControl x:name="ViewModelProperty">` to place custom user controls as needed and dynamically.